# Azure DevOps query for today and failed or resolved work items

Tags: azure, unit-testing, testing, azure-devops, automated-tests

How can i see on dashboard, a work item which today failed issues. Shortly, the query should give me state changed today to failed.

Comment: Have you tried the following steps to check if it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could try to create a shared query with the following clause:

[image: Query]

And then add this shared query to the dashboard by using the "Query Results" widget.

To list work items based on when they were created, closed, resolved, or changed—you can specify a date or use a supported macro. Use the @Today macro and specify a plus or minus number of days for relative dates.

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops).